# PHP newsfeed from people that you follow

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, twitter, feed

So I'm building a music social network in PHP and now I'm stuck at the newsfeed. It should work just as any other newsfeed (Twitter, Facebook ...) and at first point it should be as simple as possible.

I don't have any problem with displaying all the posts from my MySQL database from newest to oldest, but I only want to show posts by users that I follow.

I don't need exact code, just a theoretical explanation how to do it.

I have two MySQL tables - users and posts. Do I need anything else?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Save the user id of the users. Build an API to retrieve the information. Save it into your database and retrieve the info via ajax every minute or so. Simple.

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of which users follow who, then retrieve the posts of the users that the current logged in user is following.

You dont need new tables for this, add a new column in your users table that holds an array of id's of the users you re following.  And in your posts table a column which holds the id of the user to who the post belong.

Comment: Youre welcome, kinda curious on what youre developing, contact me if you need any help :).